# Scala: what's the reason of 'covariant type R occurs in invariant position'?

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, contravariance

Given the following example code:

```
trait Gen[T, +R] {

  def follow[K](gen: Gen[R, K]): Gen[T, K]

  def i: T
  def j: R
}
case class GenImpl[T, R](i: T, j: R) extends Gen[T, R] {

  override def follow[K](gen: Gen[R, K]): Gen[T, K] = {
    GenImpl[T, K](this.i, gen.j)
  }
}
```

The compiler will give the following error:

```
Error:(9, 17) covariant type R occurs in invariant position in type Gen[R,K] of value gen
  def follow[K](gen: Gen[R, K]): Gen[T, K]
                ^
```

however, this code cannot possibly fail a type validation in runtime. The covariant of R simply means if:

```
R1 <: R, R2 <: R
```

Then:

```
Gen[T, R1] <:< Gen[T, R]
```

So a Gen[R, K] can be a parameter of .follow() of both Gen[T, R] and Gen[T, R1]. But Gen[R1, K] can only be a parameter of .follow() of Gen[T, R1], if applied on Gen[T, R2] or Gen[T, R] it will trigger a compilation error. There is no need to set R or R1 in Gen[R/R1, K] to be contravariant to do its job.

I can't see a case that can pass compilation and fail in runtime. What do you think? Is the compiler throwing a false alarm?

Comment: I fought several of these warnings in my time and found that the compiler was never wrong in that respect. Trust the compiler. :-) Here: you use `R` as first type parameter for `Gen`, which you yourself declared as invariant, so of course, the compiler won't be happy.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have

```
class R0
class R1 extends R0
class T0
```

Then any instance of `Gen[T0, R0]` must offer the following service:

```
def follow[K](gen : Gen[R0, K]) : Gen[T0,K]
```

The variance annotation claims that `Gen[T0, R1] <:< Gen[T0, R0]`. So it must be substitutable and offer the same service. But `Gen[T0, R1]` actually offers the following service:

```
def follow[K](gen: Gen[R1, K]) : Gen[T0,K]
```

Suppose I had code like this:

```
def doFollow[K]( g : Gen[T0, R0], h : Gen[R0, K] ) : Gen[T0,K] = {
  g.follow( h )
}
```

Cool. Let's suppose I have some instances, constructed however:

```
val g0 : Gen[T0, R0]     = ???
val h0 : Gen[R0, String] = ???
val g1 : Gen[T0, R1]     = ???
```

I call `doFollow[String]( g0 , h0 )` and everything works great, I get a result.

`g1`, I have claimed in my variance annotation, is substitutable for `g0`. So now I try `doFollow[String]( g1 , h0 )`. Oops. Then I must execute, in the body of the function,

```
g1.follow[String]( h0 )
```

but `g1` only knows how to follow a `Gen[R1, String]`. `h0` is a `Gen[R0, String]`. It is **not true** that `Gen[R0, String] <:< Gen[R1, String]`, since the first parameter is declared invariant (it would have to be contravariant). So `h0` is not an acceptable argument to `g1`'s follow method, while it is an acceptable argument to `g0`'s follow method. Things of `g1`'s type, `Gen[T0, R1]`, are not in fact substitutable for things of `g0`'s type `Gen[T0, R0]`.

But your variance annotation requires that `Gen[T0, R1]` objects can be substitutable for `Gen[T0, R0]`s. They cannot, and the compiler correctly called you on it.